# Navigation Pattern in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime

My doubt is when we navigate from one page to another page in WinRT the Constructor() and On Navigated to() methods are called.
       Can we restrict the constructor calling.
As my requirement is i have to attach a new object to the datacontext while navigating again.

Comment: How would you want to restrict the constructor calling? Why is it a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an object without calling its constructor. You can set the `DataContext` in `OnNavigatedTo()`.

Comment: Because I want the state which i have set to the page before navigation .As i am navigating to the page it is filling with the previous values and whatever the properties i am changing aren't staying.

Comment: And I got the solution i use NavigationPageCache ="required" in .XAML page and i will navigate through GoBack(); The NavigationPageCache ="required" will store my application state .Thank you